# List.add not executing and returning the calling function

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a simple problem and I think I am missing something. I have a class called `CanvasState` which is just a data class holding two `List<Offset?>` variables and the class `CanvasHistory` which holds a List of `CanvasState`. Now when I am calling the `addState` method of `CanvasHistory` to add a `CanvasState` to the `statesList` variable, the `List.add` function is either not executing or it just returns the calling function. I commented the code to be more precise.

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class CanvasHistory {
  List<CanvasState> statesList = <CanvasState>[];
  late int index = 0;

  CanvasHistory({this.statesList = const <CanvasState>[]}) {
    int length = statesList.length;
    index = length - 1;
  }

  void addState(CanvasState state) {
    print("adding state \n" + state.toString()); // This print statement is printed
    statesList.add(state); // somehow this code is not executed or returns
    print("AFTER"); // This print statement is not executed.
  }
}

class CanvasState {
  final List<Offset?> _points;
  final List<Offset?> _markerPoints;

  CanvasState(this._points, this._markerPoints);

  List<Offset?> get points {
    return _points;
  }

  List<Offset?> get markerPoints {
    return _markerPoints;
  }
}
```

I have no Idea what is wrong here. I am not using asynchronous functions and it is really weird, that the second print statement is not executed.

Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Is there no error appearing in the debug console?
I notice 2 weird things in your code. One is late initialization of index variable when its already assigned the value of 0. Another is passing const<CanvasState>[] as default value for the CanvasHistory constructor. Could you try removing the const keyword from there? And the late keyword before int index as well.

Comment: Thank you! The const keyword was the problem. But I still do not get an error in my debug console which is very irritating. I am developing on a Mac with Xcode and am not used to working on a Mac.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so here is the problem:

You have a default value for your list of `const <CanvasState>[]`, The problem is that you can't add items to a `const` array. So when you try, the method throws an error and returns (if you look at your debug console, you should hopefully see an error like "add operation not supported").

To fix this, you simply have to make the default value non-constant. But oh-oh! What's this?

> The default value of an optional parameter must be constant.

Dart complains again. Here is what I recommend:

```
CanvasHistory({List<CanvasState>? statesList}) {
  if (statesList != null) {
    this.statesList = statesList;
  }
  int length = statesList.length;
  index = length - 1;
}
```

There probably is a cleaner solution, but this is the simplest one I could think of.

Also, as Abhishek Thulasi says, You don't need the `late` keyword on your index variable, you can remove it, although I don't *think* it is the cause of the bug.

Comment: Thank you! I used your answer in combination with Ali Ammars answer. The const keyword was the problem.

Answer (score 0):

the problem is that a default value will create a const list which you can't add any item to it
so you can't use add method without a error

a solution is to use a late keyword like

```
class CanvasHistory {
  late List<CanvasState> statesList ;
  late int index ;

  CanvasHistory({List<CanvasState>? statesList}) {
  this.statesList = statesList??[];
  final length = this.statesList.length;
  index = length - 1;
}
}
```